# Sparql 'langmatch' seems extremely slow on Virtuoso (DBpedia)

Tags: pagination, sparql, dbpedia

I have a sparql performance issue with DBpedia. I'd like to extract ordered information from DBpedia sparql endpoint page by page. My first example query looked like this:

```
select distinct ?objProperty ?label where {
 ?x ?objProperty <http://dbpedia.org/resource/United_States>.
 ?objProperty a owl:ObjectProperty.
 OPTIONAL{?objProperty rdfs:label ?label}
}order by ?label limit 10 offset 3
```

It was executed about 2s for me on avg(please, if you try it yourself and you see timing less than a second - increment 'offset', because it seems that DBpedia's Virtuoso is caching request results).

However the result returned is not suitable for pagination, because it is a mess of lines with labels from different languages. I want English language for labels and for precise pagination I want exactly 10 different object properties to be returned as a result. Also they have to be ordered by label. Ok. Another try:

```
select distinct ?objProperty ?label where {
 ?a ?objProperty   <http://dbpedia.org/resource/United_States>.
 ?objProperty a owl:ObjectProperty.
 OPTIONAL{?objProperty rdfs:label ?label}
 FILTER ( LANGMATCHES(lang(?label),"EN") || LANG(?label) = "")
}order by ?label limit 10 offset 3
```

For me this request returned what I expected,.. but it was executed about 7 seconds on avg!!! So sloooow!!!  Without order by and langmatch, query works about 1s on avg. Without order by but with langmatch, it takes about 6s, so it seems that langmatch eats ~ 5s on avg for this query.

I do not understand (these are questions by the way):

1. Am I doing something wrong? :)
2. Why langmatch slows query SOOO much? I wish langmatch is not regex based? If this performance issue is unavoidable using langmatch, is there a faster way to work with languages? If no, I can't imagine how semantic technologies would conquer the world in nearest future as people expect :))
3. Is there a better (faster) way to build pagination based requests than using limit/offset? If no, what is the best way to avoid performance issues like mentioned above with limit/offset?

Comment: "I wish langmatch is not regex based?"  Who said it was regex based? The docs for [langMatches](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-langMatches) say that "Returns true if language-tag (first argument) matches language-range (second argument) per the basic filtering scheme defined in RFC4647 section 3.3.1. language-range is a basic language range per Matching of Language Tags RFC4647 section 2.1. A language-range of "*" matches any non-empty language-tag string."  The [basic filtering](http://tools.ietf.org/search/rfc4647#section-3.3.1) is case insensitive, but it's not regex.

Answer (score 2):

> ### 1. Am I doing something wrong? :)

I think there's a slight issue that could make your query a bit faster.  You've got the `?label` as optional, but I think that the `filter` will only succeed when `?label` is bound, effectively making `?label` *non*-optional.  My reasoning is as follows:  in the case where `?label` is not bound, the expression `lang(?label)` will be an error (unless an implementation extends `lang()`), and both `langMatches` and `=` expect non-error values, so we'd have this reduction:

```
langMatches(lang(?label),"en") || lang(?label) = "en"
      langMatches(error, "en") || error = "en"
                         error || error
                              false
```

I'm basing this on section 17.2 of the SPARQL 1.1 recommendation, which says:

> #### [17.2 Filter Evaluation](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#evaluation)
>
> - Functions invoked with an argument of the wrong type will produce a type error. Effective boolean value arguments (labeled "xsd:boolean
>   (EBV)" in the operator mapping table below), are coerced to
>   xsd:boolean using the EBV rules in section 17.2.2.
> - Apart from BOUND, COALESCE, NOT EXISTS and EXISTS, all functions and operators operate on RDF Terms and will produce a type error if any
>   arguments are unbound.
> - Any expression other than logical-or (||) or logical-and (&&) that encounters an error will produce that error.

Based on that, I'd rewrite the query as the following.  My impression is that it's a *little* bit faster, but that might just be confirmation bias.  It's not much faster, though.

```
select distinct ?p ?label where {
  ?x ?p dbpedia:United_States .
  ?p a owl:ObjectProperty ;
     rdfs:label ?label .
  filter( langMatches(lang(?label),"en") || lang(?label) = "" )
}
order by ?label
limit 10
offset 3
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20?p%20?label%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?x%20?p%20dbpedia:United_States%20.%0D%0A%20%20?p%20a%20owl:ObjectProperty%20;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20rdfs:label%20?label%20.%0D%0A%20%20filter%28%20langMatches%28lang%28?label%29,%22en%22%29%20%7C%7C%20lang%28?label%29%20=%20%22%22%20%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aorder%20by%20?label%0D%0Alimit%2010%0D%0Aoffset%203&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

> ### 2. Why langmatch slows query SOOO much? I wish langmatch is not regex based? If this performance issue is unavoidable using langmatch, is there a faster way to work with languages?

The public DBpedia SPARQL endpoint can be a bit slow at times, but that doesn't seem to be the issue here. When I run your original query, or the new one above, query, it takes six or seven seconds to get the results.  Two things to note though:

1. `langMatch` isn't regular expression based. The docs for [`langMatches`](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-langMatches) say that "Returns true if language-tag (first argument) matches language-range (second argument) per the basic filtering scheme defined in RFC4647 section 3.3.1. language-range is a basic language range per Matching of Language Tags RFC4647 section 2.1. A language-range of "*" matches any non-empty language-tag string." The [basic filtering](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4647#section-3.3.1) is case insensitive, but it's not regex.
2. `langMatches` isn't the only thing that might be causing some slower results.  Note that to find the first 10 of something (or, in general, the *m*th through the _n_th), you have to visit *all* the elements.  You don't have to *sort* all of them, but you have to visit all of them, which means that there's no way to get just the results from the desired page (unless there's some special indexing going on;  keep making this query and maybe it will speed up overtime :)).  This leads us into the next point, though.

> ### 3. Is there a better (faster) way to build pagination based requests than using limit/offset? If no, what is the best way to avoid performance issues like mentioned above with limit/offset?

While the original and updated queries take six or seven seconds to retrieve the 10 results with `limit 10`, asking for `limit 1000`, or `limit 5000`, *also* only take about six or seven seconds. Using `limit`/`offset` is the correct way to do pagination, but ordering the results can be expensive, since to find the elements in some particular range, you have to look at *all* the elements (though you don't necessarily have to order *all* the elements).  It probably makes sense, then, to make those pages as big as possible, and to do any presentation paging locally.  E.g., instead of running 100 queries for 10 results each (100 queries × 7 seconds = 700 seconds = 11 minutes and 40 seconds), you can run 1 query for 1000 results (1 query × 7 seconds = 7 seconds), and do any important paged presentation locally.

Comment: Moving the `FILTER` inside the `OPTIONAL` is a semantically different query since putting it inside keeps more data around which means the `DISTINCT` and `ORDER BY` have more work to do (esp. since `DISTINCT` applies after `ORDER BY`).  Due to the rest of the query the end result turns out to be equivalent despite the semantic difference of the query but the original query should in principal perform better

Comment: @RobV You're right;  I mis-thought about the query.  Now, when the `filter` is outside the `optional`, it will always fail when `?label` isn't bound, right? And if that's the case, then there's really no reason to make the label optional at all, is there?

Comment: Not necessarily, in the case where there is no label then `lang(?label) = ""` should be true when `?label` is unbound (I think) so you still keep `?p` values which have no labels in addition to those with English labels.  I believe this was discussed the `lang()` behave wrt. unbound variables in another question recently but I can't remember where (possibly answers where the search functionality is awful)

Comment: Ah here it is - http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/25434/is-langmatches-true-false-or-an-error

Comment: @RobV (I posted that question.) But that was about how the matching worked in the case of empty strings, since they aren't legal language tags (although they are a specified result of `lang()`).  Here, though, I think `lang(?label)` when `?label` is unbound would be an error, so we'd have `langMatches(error,"en") || error = "en"` which would end up as `error || error` which should, I think, become `false`.  So even though `?label` is optional, we've removed all the cases where it was unbound.  (Unless of course the implementation defines some non-error behavior as an extension, but let's not

Comment: @RobV worry about that;  I can see why in the comments on that question, Jeen Broekstra said "the ability [of an implementation to define alternative behavior instead of errors] is IMHO the single greatest design flaw in the language".  Barring any of those, I think we always end up with a `?label` binding, so making it optional doesn't help anything, and _might_ decrease performance.

Comment: Yes you are write, `lang(?var)` on an unbound variable is an error, FWIW I would totally disagree with Jeen on that point

Comment: @RobV I can see some arguments for both positions.  The problem, as I see it, is that in some of these cases, it just makes it _much_ more difficult to write genuinely portable code.  E.g., in an unextended implementation, the query in question only has results that bind `?label`.  If an implementation extends `lang` to return `""` for unbound variables, then the results include unbound `?label` as well, and it seems like the only way to get around it is to write something like `filter ( bound(?label) && isLiteral(?label) && (langMatches(lang(?label),"en") || lang(?label) = "en") )`.  That

Comment: @RobV seems a bit excessive, just to ensure that an extended implementation doesn't provide more results than you want.  If you write `?resource rdfs:label ?label . filter langMatches(lang(?label),"en")` are you _really_ expecting that you might get back bindings of IRIs to `?label`?   You could, though, if the extended implementation of `lang(?label)` returns `"en"` for IRIs.  I think this actually has some ramifications on what it means for an implementation to pass the test suite tests, too, come to think of it…

Comment: However I have 3 things to say:

1. First query still works 2 secs for me (not 7 for sure :)). However sparql tweeks, which you suggested helped to improve performance for half a second :P

2. I want to know the IRI of the object property anyway even if the label is not bound, without optional, it seems, that such rows will not be included in the result.

Comment: 3. Local pagination is ok as a timely solution. But it seems a bit weird. I mean, consider the case, when DBPedia becomes super huge (and incoming object property types to US exceed 50k for example, why not?). In this case, sparql pagination becomes the only reasonable way to deal with it somehow, because loading 1000 (10000 or +) rows of the data to local server doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @user3231055 OK, you can retrieve properties that don't have a label, but right now, `filter ( langMatches(lang(?label),"en") || lang(?label) = "en" )` will remove those, because `lang(?label)` will produce an _error_ when `?label` is not bound.  However, it's not all that important anyway:  I just ran a query asking for object properties without an English label or an non-language tagged label, and there's only one:  http://dbpedia.org/ontology/followingEvent.

Answer (score 0):

Handling of language filter is up to SPARQL engine. How it stores literals? Whether it can use indexes or another technique to avoid full text scan to get literal for desired language?

You can store literal as `"chat"@en` string, but selecting all literals for english for a given property would require all property literals scan for `@en` match.

In some SPARQL engines, you can get actual execution plan. For example, here is the way to do it in Virtuoso: [Virtuoso execution plan](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtTipsAndTricksAanalyzingSPARQLQuery), however, you can't use it on public endpoint.

Query optimization, execution, query hints are very well documented for RDBMS, you can easily find out what database really does to answer your query and how to modify schema or query to get best results. IMHO, SPARQL engines are not that mature for this.